# Upload without cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I created a ASP.NET MVC project on one machine, when it came time to upload to the server, I'd just copy the Views and the Bin folder, no Controllers or Models.

However when I copied the project to another machine, the Bin folder is not being updated with a new compiled dll so I can't just copy the bin folder.

What setting do I need to tell VS2015 Community to compile the Controllers so I only need to compile the Controllers and copy just the bin folder?

Admittedly, I should've mentioned it was an ASP.NET rather than a desktop application.

Comment: Why don't you publish your project. It will take care of everything

Comment: How exactly did you copy the project to another machine?  It's not clear what's going on here.  If you open the project and compile it, the output should be there.

Comment: The is what Build : Publish is for.  The publish creates a release folder(s) with setup.exe in root just like commercial purchased software.  Choose option to create CD (which can be located on any file system not only a CD).  Then copy published folder to location where is can be run on server.

Comment: Its a ASP.NET MVC project, there is no setup.exe.  I did an XCopy to copy the source files from one machine to another.  That didn't work so I created a new project and then copied the files across.  When I release it, I use Filezilla to upload the Bin and the Views to the server.  I am not using Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what I had to do is make the site into a Web Application and there's no easy way, if there were, it'll be found at Microsoft site which the closest I found to the answer is :-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx

I created a new project and then copied the files across to the new one.  Unless there's an easier way, thats the only solution.